# arrows to next and previous month are missing in vue-bootstrap-datetimepicker?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, bootstrap-datepicker

I'm using this [date picker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-bootstrap-datetimepicker) which is working fine but appears to be missing some CSS. I have tried tons of suggestions to make this css work but with no luck. This is my current (relevant) code:

```
<template>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <div class="input-group">
                <date-picker
                        name="start-date"
                        ref="startDate">
                </date-picker>
                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" type="button" @click="$refs.startDate.dp.show()">
                        <font-awesome-icon icon="calendar-alt"></font-awesome-icon>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <div class="input-group">
                <date-picker
                        name="end-date"
                        ref="endDate">
                </date-picker>
                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" type="button" @click="$refs.endDate.dp.show()">
                        <font-awesome-icon icon="calendar-alt"></font-awesome-icon>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>

    import datePicker from 'vue-bootstrap-datetimepicker';
    // Import date picker css
    import 'pc-bootstrap4-datetimepicker/build/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css';


    export default {
        name: "DateRange",
        components: {
            myDatePicker,
        },
        date: {
            startDate: '2019-10-10',
            endDate:   '2019-09-09'
        }
    }
</script>
```

And this is how my datepicker looks like:

[image]

The arrows to the next/previous month are not visible but they are working fine. They should be visible as many of the examples the [library shows](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/). I checked inspect element and they were not overwritten by another object or anything. No warnings or errors are found. I'm truly out of ideas after having tried all the suggestions all the other questions here on SO suggest. Is there any way to get them to show up or if not maybe a custom arrows CSS but would prefer not going down that road.

Comment: Did you check this part of the documentation? https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-bootstrap-datetimepicker#icon-fonts-missing
It seems you can set the icons you want for each of the datepicker options. It may be that the icons you have installed are not the ones the datepicker it's trying to use.

Comment: @EduardoB.Galán I did try that and didn't work as well.

Comment: Maybe the datepicker package you're using it's expecting certain font-awesome version to be installed OR the other thing that comes to my mind it's that it may be some faulty style that it's causing those arrows to dissapear(?)
Deeply checking the styles with the browser inspector it's a good idea

Comment: @EduardoB.Galán Unfortunately nothing seems to be wrong there. I've also never imagined being disappointed that nothing is wrong with the code :p

Comment: Please provide an example of the issue via SO snippet or JSFiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the following to your after the `<script>` tag and this will make custom CSS:

```
<style>
    i.custom-button-previous:before {
        content: "<<";
    }

    i.custom-button-next:before {
        content: ">>";
    }
</style>
```

This will put arrows of the given shape inside content in those two places where the arrows are missing

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation, I found that bootstrap css is needed to run this picker.

[image]

I can't see bootstrap import in your code provided above which should be something like:

> import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';

Please try to import this or update the question.

Comment: I've tried your suggestion and it didn't help unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

The date picker uses glyphicons icons for the arrows. Can you check if you have "glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff" file getting imported in your website, if not include below css

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  src: url('http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff'), url('http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff') format('woff');}
}
```

Comment: That was not it unfortunately

Comment: Can add a screenshot of the network tab in chrome with font filter enabled in dev tools

Comment: Can you add the screenshot? it will help to debug.

Answer (score 0):

Add this, It works for me.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
```